# Why ImportByteArray when generate image from bytes

Tags: image-processing, image, binary, number-bases

I was trying to generate an image from a list of bytes so I only had to `Import` an `Image` once as I want to store a Base64Encoded string in a database using the Imported bytes.

I found one solution but not sure why `ImportByteArray` is needed when generating an `Image` from bytes?

```
image = Import[
  "http://www.wolfram.com/common/framework/img/spikey.en.png", "Image"]

imageBytes = 
 Import["http://www.wolfram.com/common/framework/img/spikey.en.png", 
  "Byte"]

imageBinary = 
 Import["http://www.wolfram.com/common/framework/img/spikey.en.png", 
  "Binary"]

imageBytes === imageBinary 
(*true*)

imageBytes === Normal[BinarySerialize[image]]
(*False*)
```

To Generate `Image` from bytes, one solution is:

```
decodedImage = Image[ImportByteArray[ByteArray[imageBytes]], "Byte"]

decodedImage === image
(*True*)
```

Why do you need the `ImportByteArray`?  You should be able to:

```
imageData = Image[imageBytes, "Byte"]
(*ERROR Image::imgarray*)
```

This also does not work:

```
imageData = Image[ByteArray[imageBytes], "Byte"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First, the full text of `Image::imgarray` sheds light on one issue:

```
Image::imgarray: The specified argument ByteArray[2.3 kB] should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers.
```

Specifically, `Image` does not know how to turn a vector of numbers into a matrix. Second, and more interestingly, `Image` does not work with image formats, but the equivalent, underlying data. Simply, `imageBytes` is still in its original format

```
In[14]:= ByteArrayFormat@ByteArray[imageBytes]
Out[14]= "PNG"
```

So, `ImportByteArray` is needed to convert this from formatted data to raw data.